# How can I instantiate this class?

Tags: c#, instantiation

Consider this declaration with generics:

```
public class BaseNode<TNode> where TNode : BaseNode<TNode>
{
    public class Node : BaseNode<Node>
    {
        public Node() { }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create an instance of class `Node` from outside the base class? I have used this pattern before, but always leaving the derived classes outside of the base class.

How do you write the following without a compiler error?

```
var obj = new BaseNode<Node>.Node(); 
// error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Node' could not be found
```

Have I created an un-instantiable class? Can it be initialized via reflection?

Comment: Why not define `Node` outside of `BaseNode`?

Comment: I think you either have to create a constructor on the parent class and instantiated the Node class there or create a method that will instantiate the Node class.

Comment: This is an academic question. I just happened to create it like this for aesthetic reasons and then I realized that I kinda put the key in a locked drawer so to speak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can instantiate that monster.  All you have to do is create your own class that inherits from `Node`:

```
public class MyNode : BaseNode<MyNode>.Node
{
}
```

Then you can instantiate it like this:

```
BaseNode<MyNode> obj = new BaseNode<MyNode>();
```

Why you would want to do this, though, is a different matter entirely...

Comment: +1 on "Why you would want to do this..." (not to mention a valid way to instantiate a Node (sort of)).

Answer (score 1):

Add a static factory method:

```
public static Node Create<T>()
{
    return // your new Node
}
```

And call it thusly:

```
var foo = BaseNode<Node>.Create<Node>();
```

Comment: You can't call `var foo = BaseNode.Create<Node>();` without a type parameter.

Comment: There is no `BaseNode` type, only a generic `BaseNode<>` type, unless you're also proposing that he make that not generic

Comment: You still can't call `BaseNode<Node>.Create()` because `Node` is not a known type.

Comment: Ah, what a mess.  I guess you would need a static, non-generic class to do it.

Comment: Yep. Agreed. The reason for wanting to do this is a more interesting question.